# Can't find C++ include file for Drawing functions

Tags: c++, winapi, cygwin

Can anyone tell me what the relevant include file would be for `CreateRectRgnIndirect`, `CreateSolidBrush`, `FillRgn`, `CreatePen` and so on?

I'm trying to work through errors like:

```
build/Release/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/mywindow.o:mywindow.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference
to _imp__CreateRectRgnIndirect@4' build/Release/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/mywindow.o:mywindow.cpp:
(.text+0xca): undefined reference to _imp__CreateSolidBrush@4'
```

I cannot find it in any Google searches I've done so far.

Comment: Googled it. First thing that comes up is `#include <Windows.h>`

Comment: It lists that right in the msdn docs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: [CreateRectRgnIndirect](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=FhVDU5vyCIiLtQaVr4DwBw#q=CreateRectRgnIndirect) works well for me?!??

Comment: I have that header already. #include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
and still get the error.?

Comment: @bartThanks for the constructive critsism.

Comment: I've reaD ALL THE PAGES YOU'VE DESCRIBED AND STILL NO LUCK.

Comment: what is the error message you get, verbatim?

Comment: I get this:build/Release/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/mywindow.o:mywindow.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateRectRgnIndirect@4'
build/Release/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/mywindow.o:mywindow.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateSolidBrush@4'
etcetera..

Comment: I do not believe Cygwin does "Windows.h", you will need a Microsoft compiler.

Comment: It is a linker error so header should be fine probably this should help [Win32_Cygwin] http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.programming.win32-api

Comment: @imran Clearly Windows.h is here and has been included. Otherwise, how would the code have compiled? This is a linker error and so unrelated to the header files.

Answer (score 6):

This is a linker error. These functions have been declared, but not defined. Therefore you need to provide a definition. That's typically done on Windows using an import library. In the case of these GDI functions it is `Gdi32.lib`. Supply that library to your linker and all will be well.

To find out which library to use for a specific Win32 function, consult the documentation. For instance, take [`CreateRectRgnIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183515.aspx). At the bottom of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183515.aspx) is a list of requirements, including the header file that declares the function, and the library that defines it.

In this case you are told to include `Windows.h` and link against `Gdi32.lib`. Clearly you already did the former because otherwise you would not have got as far as linking.

Answer (score 1):

My error here was because I was missing a library in my compile command (libgdi32.a), and after that, I also wasn't putting -lgdi32 AFTER my source code, as in:

Incorrect (undefined reference error at compile time):

```
gcc -lgdi32 source.cpp
```

Correct:

```
gcc source.cpp -lgdi32
```

Found out thanks to this page:
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use